# How to move the first word in a string to the end?

Tags: java

I wanna change `INLET CENTRE STN BAY 1` to `CENTRE STN BAY 1 INLET` And this is my code:

```
public class TST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "INLET CENTRE STN BAY 1";
        search(st);
        System.out.println(st);
    }

    private static String search(String st) {
        String[] parts = st.split(" ", 2);
        String firstWord = parts[0];
        String rest = parts[1];
        return rest + " " + firstWord;
    }
}
```

But it seems doesn't work, is there any other way to address this issue?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? Maybe provide a sample output you're getting?

Comment: What does “It doesn’t work” mean? What is the output? What are the errors?

Comment: You're not assigning the result to anything. The call to the method is lost. You're just printing out the original string.

Comment: Combine the last two lines in the main methos like this `System.out.println(search(st));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```
String input = "INLET CENTRE STN BAY 1";
String output = input.replaceAll("^(\\S+) (.*)$", "$2 $1");
System.out.println(output);  // CENTRE STN BAY 1 INLET
```

Answer (score 1):

To move the last word to the front, you should use String's [lastIndexOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String st = "INLET CENTRE STN BAY 1";
    int splitIdx = st.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String lastWord = st.substring(splitIdx + 1);
    String newStr = st.substring(0, splitIdx);
    System.out.println(lastWord + " " + newStr);
}
```

To move the first front to the back, you can use `split` like you have to extract the word and then you can use a simple string concatenation to rebuild the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tokens = st.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = tokens[0];
    String newStr = tokens[1];
    System.out.println(newStr + " " + firstWord);
}
```